# How can I replace a space in a string with an underscore in C#?

Tags: c#

I have strings such as:

```
var abc = "Menu Link";
```

Is there a simple way I can change the space to an underscore?

Comment: yes, use string.Replace() method

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want to do it in place:

```
abc = abc.Replace(" ", "_");
```

Although do realize a *new* `string` instance will be created; it's not actually done in the same memory location - `String` is an immutable type.

Answer (score 9):

Using `String.Replace(char,char)` instead of `String.Replace(string, string)` should be much faster. i.e.

```
abc = abc.Replace(' ', '_');
```

Comment: *should be* or *is*?

Comment: Can you prove this?

Comment: This indicates that char replace is faster (as expected) - see Sergey Kalinichenko's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129996/string-replacechar-char-or-replacestring-string

Answer (score 1):

simply add `.Replace()` function at the end of the string.

```
abc = abc.Replace(' ', '_');
```