# String.Replace(char, char) or Replace(string, string)?

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance

Is there a performance difference between String.Replace(char, char) and String.Replace(string, string) when I just need to replace once character with another?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is: I ran a quick experiment, and it looks like the string version is about 3 times slower.

```
    string a = "quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
    DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; i++) {
        var b = a.Replace('o', 'b');
        if (b.Length == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; i++) {
        var b = a.Replace("o", "b");
        if (b.Length == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    DateTime te = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", t2-t1, te-t2);
```

1.466s vs 4.583s

This is not surprising, because the overload with strings needs an extra loop to go through all characters of the `oldString`. This loop runs exactly one time, but the overhead is still there.

Comment: +1 Out of interest, is anyone able to reverse engineer the overloads of System.String.ReplaceInternal? I'm interested to see if the Dev observed immutability on the char overload :)

Answer (score 6):

I would *expect* `string.Replace(char, char)` to potentially be faster, as it can allocate exactly the right amount of space. I doubt that it'll make a significant performance difference in many real world apps though.

More importantly, I'd say it's more readable - it's clearer that you really will end up with a string of the same length.

Answer (score 3):

`String.Replace(char, char)` is faster. The reason is simple:

- Char replacement does not need to allocate a string with a different size, String replacement needs to find out the new size first or use a `StringBuilder` for the replacement
- Char replacement doesn't need to do a check with a range of a string. Imagine you have a string like `ABCACABCAC` and you want to replace `ABC`. You need to find out if 3 chars are matching, when working with chars you need only to find one char.